# How to remove every special character except for the hyphen and the apostrophe inside and between words words?

Tags: python, regex

As an example i already managed to break the sentence
"That's a- tasty tic-tac. Or -not?" into an array of words like this:
`words['That's', 'a-', 'tasty', 'tic-tac.','Or', '-not?']`.

Now i have to remove every special character i don't need and get this: `words['That's', 'a', 'tasty', 'tic-tac','Or', 'not']`

my actual current code looks like this:

`pattern = re.compile('[\W_]+')`

`for x in range(0, file_text.__len__()):`

```
for y in range(0, file_text[x].__len__()):

    word_list.append(pattern.sub('', file_text[x][y]))
```

I have a whole text that i first turn into lines and words and then into just words

Comment: Please try to provide sample input (a few words, you have some already) and expected output (to make your goal as clear as possible) to this kind of questions

Comment: Wait, do you mean hyphens *and* single apostrophes? If yes, use `re.sub(r'\b([-'])\b|[\W_]', r'\1', text)`

Comment: See https://ideone.com/K1ioEj

Comment: I edited the post because it wasn't clear enough what my intentions were

Comment: You say you have a list called `words` with the words. Just use that.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you, it works! Would you please explain how it works, regex looks like gibberish to me

Comment: re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9_$=&?%\+-@^<|>":;`~!*()[\]\s]+', '', string)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i dont know how to reopen it, i just signed up to ask this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
r"\b([-'])\b|[\W_]"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/34SR7D/1) (the demo is a bit modified so that `[\W_]` could not match newlines as the input at the demo site is a single multiline string).

**Regex details**

- `\b([-'])\b` - a `-` or `'` that are enclosed with word chars (letters, digits or underscores) (NOTE you may require to only exclude matching these symbols when enclosed with letters if you use `(?<=[^\W\d_])([-'])(?=[^\W\d_])`)
- `|` - or
- `[\W_]` - any char other than a letter or a digit.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/K1ioEj):

```
import re
words = ["That's", 'a-', 'tasty', 'tic-tac.','Or', '-not?']
rx = re.compile(r"\b([-'])\b|[\W_]")
print( [rx.sub(r'\1', x) for x in words] )
# => ["That's", 'a', 'tasty', 'tic-tac', 'Or', 'not']
```